# Finding a distribution name by its formula

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, reference-request

I'm looking for a search engine which given the formula of function returns the name of the associated function or probability distribution, if any, up to constants.

For instance, if I input:

$$ f = k x^{k-1} e^{-x^k} $$

the engine should return a reference to the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).
This would be useful to find out if the functions I'm studying have been already covered in literature.

Comment: Unlikely to be useful for you, but whenever you can phrase (some aspect of) the mathematical object you're interested in as an integer sequence, I often find a lot of success computing a couple terms and putting them into the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) search engine.